# Facing issue in Teamcity connect ECONNREFUSED "127.0.0.1:37117

Tags: teamcity

Facing issue in Teamcity connect ECONNREFUSED "127.0.0.1:37117
While Trying to run the scripts in teamcity not able to trigger the build please can someone suggest any solution or what can I do

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:35127

at TCPConnectwrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)

at TCPConnectwrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)

at BrowserConnection._runBrowser (/opt/buildagent/work/e781e779b1d9c18b/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/connection/index.ts:21 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Searched in Google YouTube not able to find any solution not able to find anything relevant as facing in teamcity

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means the server isn't listening/blocked. Is TeamCity on the same system that you're running this script?